# How to append node to xml file in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight

I have a xml file in ClientBin folder with the name XMLFile1.xml.
There are three nodes in file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<People>
  <Person FirstName="Ram" LastName="Sita"/>
  <Person FirstName="Krishna" LastName="Radha"/>
  <Person FirstName="Heer" LastName="Ranjha"/>
</People>
```

I can read nodes from file like that:

```
   public class Person
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
        }



private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    Uri filePath = new Uri("XMLFile1.xml", UriKind.Relative);
    WebClient client1 = new WebClient();
    client1.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client1_DownloadStringCompleted);

    client1.DownloadStringAsync(filePath);
}


  void client1_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
                IEnumerable<Person> list = from p in doc.Descendants("Person")
                                           select new Person
                                           {
                                               FirstName = (string)p.Attribute("FirstName"),
                                               LastName = (string)p.Attribute("LastName")
                                           };
                DataGrid1.ItemsSource = list;
            }
        }
```

But i cant append node to this. What i have done yet with XDocument and XMLDocument gave me  compile errors. Thanks.

**Update** : For example I have tried something like that:

string FirstName = "Ferhad";
        string LastName = "Cebiyev";

```
    XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument();
    string path = "C:\\Users\\User\Desktop\\temp\\SilverlightApplication3\\SilverlightApplication3.Web\\ClientBin\\XMLFile1.xml";
    xmlDoc.Load(path);
    xmlDoc.Add(new Person { FirstName=FirstName, LastName = LastName});

    xmlDoc.Save(path);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
xmlDoc.Add(new Person { FirstName=FirstName, LastName = LastName});
```

Two issues:

- That tries to add to the *root* of the document. There's already a root element, so that will fail.
- That's trying to add a `Person`to the document. You want to add an `XElement`.

So you probably want:

```
xmlDoc.Root.Add(new XElement("Person",
                             new XAttribute("FirstName", FirstName),
                             new XAttribute("LastName", LastName)));
```

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev: Ah, yes - you're trying to use files directly. You can't do that in Silverlight, but that has nothing to do with XML. Read up on Silverlight storage. Next, please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list - you should *never* post a question with compilation errors without including the errors.